# go-zookeeper connect not return when zkserver down

Tags: go, apache-zookeeper

I have a question regarding zookeeper, I am trying to implement simple service discovery with zookeeper in go, I am using go-zookeeper:

https://github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper

My question is when the zookeeper servers goes down, the connect function never return value. for example:

```
maxBufferSize := zk.WithMaxBufferSize(1536 * 1024)
maxConnBufferSize := zk.WithMaxConnBufferSize(1536 * 1024)
conn, ec, err := zk.Connect(servers, 3*time.Second, maxBufferSize, maxConnBufferSize)
```

the `zk.Connect` function don't return. Now for example if I want set a timeout and a max retry nums, what do I need to set two nums.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The link you provided returns a 404

Comment: Try with single server and check before you can able to ping the ip or host, if it works then check other servers are able to ping then try all with servers.